# Can't Load Sheet in Google Visualization API Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to use Google Charts to add to a website for my company, and am running into problems when connecting the Sheet.  I started from the basics and tried to recreate the pie example in the tutorial, but have the chart load the data from a sheet, rather than creating the table in the code.  I am clearly doing something wrong.  When I look at the console, it reads:

Error while parsing the 'sandbox' attribute: 'allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox' is an invalid sandbox flag.

Do I not have something set up correctly?

I know this is probably a very basic question, but I am just starting out and would appreciate help.  Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">        </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.

  function drawChart() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WvVr748_MgWa0goyfwlMB2AX_AYtfvXnsLP8N1kyaek');
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  var data = response.getDataTable();

}


    var options = {'title':'How Many Donuts I Ate',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300};

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

</script>
</head>
  <body>
  <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should contain your whole "draw chart procedure" in `drawChart()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Callback that creates and populates a data table,
// instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
// draws it.

function drawChart() {
var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WvVr748_MgWa0goyfwlMB2AX_AYtfvXnsLP8N1kyaek');
query.send(handleQueryResponse);


function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  var data = response.getDataTable();
}


var options = {'title':'How Many Donuts I Ate',
               'width':400,
               'height':300};

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `google.visualization.Query.send` function is *async* i would suggest to change the chart rendering flow to:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


function drawChart() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WvVr748_MgWa0goyfwlMB2AX_AYtfvXnsLP8N1kyaek');
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {

    if (response.isError()) {
        console.log('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }


    var options = {
        'title': 'How Many Donuts I Ate',
        'width': 400,
        'height': 300
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    var data = response.getDataTable();
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

---

Regarding the error message:

> Error while parsing the 'sandbox' attribute:
>   'allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox' is an invalid sandbox flag.

It has nothing to do with Google API but concerns Chrome browser, AFAIK it is **not** supported to specify `allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox` attribute for in current version (`desktop Chrome 45`). But staring from [Chrome 46+](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox/index.html) it is supported to specify this flag (just verified it with `Chrome Canary 47`)